# How can I filter statistics from facebook ads api using the python sdk?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to filter by data ranges, just to see the performance on a daily basis, or for the last day, last week, last month...etc.

How can I add a date parameter different from start_date or end_date because? I guess those parameters are just only for the start and end date of the campaign but they might not give me the result I want.

My current code is this one:

```
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import objects

my_app_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
my_app_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
my_access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

me = objects.AdUser(fbid='10153166606850429')
my_accounts = list(me.get_ad_accounts())


my_account = objects.AdAccount('act_XXXXXXXXXXXX')

params = {
'start_date': '2015-02-01',
}
fields = {
'impressions',
'clicks',
'spent',
}

stats = my_account.get_ad_campaign_stats(fields=fields, params=params)

# print stats
for stat in stats:
    print stat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adstatistics/v2.2#filtering), It looks like you have the field name wrong.

The API lists `start_time` and `end_time` but also mentions you should have both a start and end.

```
params = {
    'start_time': '2015-02-01',
    'end_time': '2015-02-02',
}
```

Hope this helps!